# NHibernate TooManyRowsAffectedException

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

I'm getting this error while flushing changes to db. I am changing only the `Matricula` property. I have tried to flush changes before to make sure isn't there anything pending and in deed it does nothing.

Next thing I do is change that property and inmediately after flush changes.
 The SQL generated is correct, however it says that 212 rows where affected when only 1 should have been.

```
[16:49:27,122] NHibernate.SQL - DEBUG: Batch commands:
command 0:UPDATE Ordenes_Bonos SET Matricula = @p0 WHERE IdOrden = @p1 AND 
IdBono = @p2;@p0 = '020012' [Type: String (4000:0:0)], @p1 = 115862 [Type: 
Int32 (0:0:0)], @p2 = 10 [Type: Int32 (0:0:0)]

[16:49:27,566] NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener - 
ERROR: Could not synchronize database state with session
NHibernate.AdoNet.TooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned 
unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 212; expected: 1
```

So the next thing I do is check the same query directly on the database in case there were so many rows altered due to triggers (I don't think so but just in case):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE Ordenes_Bonos
SET    Matricula = '020012'  
WHERE  IdOrden = '115862'
   AND IdBono = '10'

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
ROLLBACK;
```

The output for that is 1.

So why is NHibernate saying 212 rows changed over that UPDATE?

Comment: do you have triggers setup in the DB that would get kicked off from your update?

Comment: Yes there are triggers that may kick off from that update. But in that case my SQL query shouldn't say so?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is caused because of the triggers you said get kicked off from the executing statement.

Triggers run within the transaction of the executing statement which is your NHibernate update. If you haven't explicitly started a transaction, Nhibernate will use an [implicit transaction](https://ayende.com/blog/3775/nh-prof-alerts-use-of-implicit-transactions-is-discouraged) in SQL.

So Nhiberate is seeing those trigger updates as part of its transaction and is throwing your error.

So you've got 2 options.

1. update all the triggers with `set NOCOUNT ON` to suppress the number of rows affected
2. removed the triggers and move them into EventListeners in NHibernate.

Comment: I can't go for any of those 2 solutions since I cannot alter nor remove the triggers (I am not the database admin). Isn't there a way to just ignore this? And why if I execute the SQL statement myself ROWCOUNT is just 1?